# Paypal in windows phone 7 App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, paypal, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone 7 application. In my app user can make purchases. The client need to use paypal for payments.

I found paypal APIs for all other phones (IPhone, Android, Blackberry). But there is no API for windows phone. Is windows phone support paypal ?.
Is there any other alternative method if there is no paypal API for windows phone ?

Thanks

Comment: Amazon Mobile allows purchasing, but I believe they do so via web services. This might be your avenue. Also, PayPal just released their app to Marketplace, and I suspect they're doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use paypal in windows phone 7 by the Mobile Express Checkout method with the help of a webbrowser control. I implemented and succeeded the paypal implementation in windows phone.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-express-checkout

Hope the above links will help others too to implement paypal in windows phone 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think in-app purchasing currently is not available for Windows Phone 7.5.

This wil be the feature of WP8 exclusively!